# Are there any special variations of uuencoding / uudecoding?

Tags: encoding, decoding, uuencode, uudecode

I have written a small program which can encode/decode a text with uuencode/uudecode. The code is based on the algorithm described on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuencoding). It works fine when I encode/decode a string. But I have found a uuencoded file which I can't decode. [This](http://www.webutils.pl/UUencode) website can decode the file, but when I encode it again I don't get the same file. In addition, when I decode only one line of the file I don't get readable text (neither with my program nor with the decoder I linked before). But in uuenoding all lines are independent from each other - this must be able.

Do someone know whether there are some special variations of the uuenoding, which are not described on Wikipedia? I can decode some strings so my decoder can't be totally wrong. Perhaps someone has written his own decoder, so I post the whole file:

```````````
begin 666 Restricted.zip
M4$L#!!0````(`%T[="_]<LYX`P(``'0#```.````4F5S=')I8W1E9"YT>'1M
M4\MNVT`0NQOP/TSNM@PT0!/X4N16`RE0%.GC.I9&TE;2CKH/J_K[<E;IX]"+
M'UJ20W)6^]U3)SX=]KO][D*]SD(7XHD2CX/S'26EU`L%U_6)9@E1?46NQ4,7
MR?E6P\3)J:=%@ABZY7'$P2MO"0J1GGT3Z;B1YJ#?I4ZT:!X;N@KI34)%3Y%6
MS8#>A#I-&[;E`-H%'(EY@G[/(-I',=GI;XN"H49?''YXT#LE]BNU.<!&,*(W
M0&4Y7V#,F_&11NV<-TNU-!D!>HZP5"MF91^YE0-D&H2C5CAL\T&P:#/'A*<+
M#F6(!IEXW?Q?13Q=@P[XLBHJ>L[UX,;U8+`"X3I)0S^RJX=Q+3-28)@@+IK:
MEAD@AQRM7DY)ICG%BK[:(,\=L$C>20*EUCR/8BP'&'H+.OT5:+`V>,*NK$%9
MZ<;>Q1X"1WJOBZ#_8HQ+`3?K%(U<1U-:7.HI6A]_+/V[\RU,J]DW!SMV@<37
M89W+>5QCL6/"MDHTQPV&UT5-<R!=?%D)MG^AR&Y3^>]::JP0H2MZ4>3UR?F,
M[>18,L'"..I2K'.,BP8TF<K)YT_/IG1S#<@VZ^,KX$QO'[\\WC_<W;V[?_-P
MW>^`/%.?TGP^G99EJ29MCC^K6JL\G%H78CJQC[CGU=S/V_M2KEN<A0?;A5U`
M[AC.U2*6OUOE0<KD#Q#\MM_]`E!+`0(4`!0````(`%T[="_]<LYX`P(``'0#
M```.``````````$`(`"V@0````!297-T<FEC=&5D+G1X=%!+!08``````0`!
+`#P````O`@``````
`
end
```````````

Comment: I *like* this question.  Did you write your decode in normal C, or are you using Perl’s builtin `unpack` function, which supports the uuencode format directly?

Comment: I wrote the whole program by myself and not with C but with Scala.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! The problem was that I did not notice the first line. This line holds information about the data encoded - a file named `Restricted.zip`. So the decoded data is a ZIP file which I just had to unpack.

I got a text file named `Restricted.txt` which contains the readable data.

The problem was so easy, but it took me days to see its solution.

That's a good change over to packing algorithms - perhaps the next thing I do is writing my own program which can pack/unpack zip files.

Comment: Hey can you help me for this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37606722/bad-format-for-last-line-in-uuencoded-data and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37571069/some-uuencoded-files-are-not-decoding-properly-in-c-sharp